# pg_dump with user dont superadmin and large objects

Tags: postgresql

I have started a long career for export databases with users who are not superadmins. But I found the problem that in the new versions of postgresql only superadmins can access large objects.

```
ERROR: permission denied for large object 5141
```

There is no way to do this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL LARGE OBJECTS TO role_name;
```

I thought making a triger and when a large object was created (table pg_catalog.pg_largeobject), give my user permissions. But triggers on system catalog are not allowed.

I have come to the conclusion that you can not export if you are not superuser. Is this right?

Comment: Was this database upgraded from 8.4 or earlier? It [looks like](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pg_upgrade/version.c) `pg_upgrade` should have given you a separate script to initialise large object permissions. If this wasn't run, it might explain your problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, because I did not. But I think it was a clean install

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The doc for [`lo_compat_privileges`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html) explains the situation:

> **lo_compat_privileges** (boolean)
>
> In PostgreSQL releases prior to 9.0, large objects did not have access privileges and were, therefore, always readable and writable by
>   all users. Setting this variable to on disables the new privilege
>   checks, for compatibility with prior releases. The default is off.
>   Only superusers can change this setting.
>
> Setting this variable does not disable all security checks related to large objects — only those for which the default behavior has
>   changed in PostgreSQL 9.0. For example, lo_import() and lo_export()
>   need superuser privileges regardless of this setting.

Note that this can be set per database with:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET lo_compat_privileges=on;
```

When `lo_compat_privileges` is set to its default `OFF`, access is not limited to superusers, but controlled. Each large object has an owner and that owner has full rights. Read permissions can be given for each large object at a time (by owner or superuser) with :

```
GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT loid TO rolename;
```

where `rolename` may also be `PUBLIC` to mean "everyone", see [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) for the details.

On the other hand, I don't think it's possible to set permissions on all large objects of a database with a single command, or in advance on not-yet existing contents, since [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) has no support for large objects, and as you note, triggers are not an option.

A non-superuser who has SELECT permissions on all the large objects of a database can pg_dump this database without error.