# PostgreSQL: Permission denied for large object

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

When migrating from my development to staging environment, I encountered the following error during a hibernate sql call to the PostgreSQL database on the staging server.

There is no error in the development environment. I am assuming it is a privileges issue on the satging db. However, I have never seen this error and I do not know where to look. Can anyone advise?

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for large object 109138
>       at org.postgresql.largeobject.BlobInputStream.read(BlobInputStream.java:123)
>       at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
>       at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
>       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractString(DataHelper.java:71)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/50CF651C.9040004@computer.org could be one reason

Comment: A similar question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/26381604/3503187

Comment: to quickly sort out this situation you can add `lo_compat_privilege = on` in `postgresql.conf`

Comment: you should add as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.0, large objects have permissions (column `lomacl` of table `pg_largeobject_metadata`). By default, nobody except the owner (column `lomowner`) has any permissions for a large object.

So it seems that either it is a version migration problem (e.g., you didn't use `pg_dump` from the newer version to create the dump), or you are trying to access the large objects as a different user in your staging environment.

Comment: yup, that's it. For me it was the latter.

Answer (score 8):

In `postgresql.conf` change `lo_compat_privileges` to `on`. This worked for me

Comment: This was a quick fix (migrates from 9.? to 10)

Comment: A nice answer, is important to note that after migrating to a new postgres server is necesesary to check configuration is the same in "postgresql.conf", to avoid this missconfigurations.